# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed

Tags: c#, linq

Here im getting Error while im planing to joing more than two tables.

```
public List<EmailContent> RABsalesHeadStatusRejectBody(string EnqId)
{
    List<EmailContent> E_mail = new List<EmailContent>();
    var join_Body = new EmailContent();
    var line = Environment.NewLine;

    if (EnqId != null)
    {
        var x = 
            from n in db.EMS_ENQUIRYREGISTRATION_MASTER
            join _categeory in db.EMS_CATEGORY_MASTER on n.CATEGORY_ID equals _categeory.CATEGORY_ID
            join sal in db.EMS_USER_MASTER on n.Saleshead equals sal.USER_ID 
            where n.ENQUIRY_CODE == EnqId
            select new RegisterationMaster
            {
                CATEGORY_ID = _categeory.CATEGORY_ID,
                RECEIVED_BY = n.RECEIVED_BY
            };
    }

}
```

Please Suggest me how can i join more tha two table

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, its wise to make your code tidy, you can press the edit button and indent correctly. it makes it easier to read, and helps us help you

Comment: can the object Saleshead? for example: n.Saleshead.ID equals sal.USER_ID

Comment: ˋSaleshead equals sal.USER_ID´ check this equality. What's the n.Saleshead?

Comment: @Llazar Thank you soo much for helping me Here User_Id and Saleshead  id is not matching